# OOP and WordPress plugin theme supporting

Tags: php, oop, wordpress

I'm trying to create the WordPress plugin using OOP and I got stuck at the beginning. I would like to add the ability to modify the page header via WordPress panel.

Users should be able to change header image and text. I found out that add_theme_support function will be definitely helpful.

Initially I made the attempt to create header section in the Apperance menu of WordPress panel, so I have tried this code:

```
class Plugin{
    public function __construct(){
        if (is_admin()) {
           add_action('admin_init', array($this,'admin_init'));
        }
    }
    public function admin_init(){
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array($this,'customHeader') );
    }
    public function customHeader(){
        add_theme_support('custom-header');
    }
}
$plugin=new Plugin();
```

Unfortunately something is wrong and it doesn't give any result. Header editing page does not appear in the admin panel.

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work and where there is a mistake ?

Comment: "It works" and "But it doesn't" are not problem descriptions.

Comment: In the first case header section is properly added to Apperance section of WordPress panel, but second gives no reasult, even errors

Comment: "even errors", which errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the hook for 'after_setup_theme' at 'admin_init' but this needs to be set earlier.

```
class Plugin {
    public function __construct(){
         add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array($this,'customHeader') );
    }

    public function customHeader(){
        add_theme_support('custom-header');
    }
}

$plugin=new Plugin();
```

You wouldn't only want to add theme support when you are in the admin area.